# Storing error codes and messages globally in Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, error-handling

I have a Django app which when presented with some user error (i.e URL does not exist or no permissions), it will do `messages.add_message`. The message contains a link to an explanation of the error at `/error/<id>`. If I want to re-use the error id and message, how do I do it? I was thinking something like this:

`errors = {1 : "Error message for error id 1", 2 : "Error message for error id 2"}`

Where could I store such a dictionary so that I can access it in all of my views?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 're-use'; where do you want to set it and where to want to read and display it (I assume that's what you mean by re-use).

Comment: Usually error messages are stored in log files, format could be pretty much whatever you like, but you can also store them in database.

Comment: I don't know where it needs to be set. The dictionary is read in the view, and the error id and text is given to `messages.add_message`, which is then shown in the template.

Comment: @user1585811 it's not django errors, it's errors which I'm setting and displaying, which is unrelated to system errors. These are things like validation errors which are given to the users, not the system.

Comment: alright, storing in database is one option but it comes with performance issues, another thing which you can try is to store it in cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a view that maps to a `url` like `/error/<id>`. Then inside the view have the dictionary `errors = {1 : "Error message for error id 1", 2 : "Error message for error id 2"}` or alternatively inside a file called `error_codes.py` and import it into your `views.py` . Then simply parse the `<id>` passed in the `url` and return a `template` with the correct `error code`.

To ensure that this dictionary of error codes is available across all your requests, use write custom [Django Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs). Implement `process_template_response(self, request, response)` and alter the `response.context_data` by adding your `error_code_dictionary` to it. Will ensure that every response has the error dictionary available across your http responses rendered in templates and elsewhere.

Comment: I would like to display the error message on a page before the user clicks "More information". for example, when a form is incorrectly submitted, this message will show `"Error code 15: Incorrect filetype"`. "Error code 15" is a link to the error explanation page. I really need to be able to access the error number and message in *any* view of my application.

Comment: I edited my answer. Use `Django Middleware` to access all your error codes across your pages and then the view to link up the `error code urls`