# Adding error codes to Django

Tags: django, response, django-rest-framework

Currently, when an error occurs in my Django application this is what is returned as an error:

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I saw that i can specify custom error message like this

```
Field(error_messages = { 'required': '12' })
```

I would like to know if it's possible to tell Django to return error codes along plain text error? And not replace it with error_messages. If it's possible, what's the best way to do it?

Something like this would be nice:

```
{
    "name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "error_code": 12
 }
```

This way I could translate the various errors in different languages in my client and not on the server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071173/storing-error-codes-and-messages-globally-in-django

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged django-rest-framework. If indeed you're using DRF, you can do this with a [custom exception handler](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions#custom-exception-handling).